# MSBuild with multiple dependency projects/solutions

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, dependencies, msbuild-task, solution-folders

I have a repository and it has multiple solutions and for each solution there are dependencies of other project (in other solutions too). How can resolve dependency issues with the help of msbuild commandline

Comment: What dependency issues do you mean? Any error message about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can resolve dependency issues with the help of msbuild commandline.

Sorry but the answer is negative if the dependency issues you mentioned above are about project references or project dependencies. [Msbuid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2019) is platform used to build applications. If you get any dependency issues during the build process, you have to locate the issue first, then try to resolve it by yourself.

So if you get any dependency issues, you can use command like `msbuild xx.sln ... -v:Detailed` to get more info in the output log, but there's no switches in msbuild can help resolve the issue automatically. Set a [higher log level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/obtaining-build-logs-with-msbuild?view=vs-2019#set-the-level-of-detail) in command-line for better trouble-shooting.